# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: TestJni.print(LA;)V error on Ubuntu

Tags: java, c++, c, ubuntu, java-native-interface

I know this is an often-seen problem and after search on the web, problem still not solved. -Djava.library.path is already added to the command.

Here is my java file

```
public class TestJni
{
        public native void print(A a);

        static{
                System.loadLibrary("MyJni");
        }

        public static void main(String []args){
                new TestJni().print(new A());
        }
}
class A{
        void show(){
                System.out.println("In a show function");

        }
}
```

I am trying to create an instance 'a' which is A class.
Pass it to native method print and let native method to invoke show() method.
Compile .java into .class

```
javac TestJni.java
```

Now I have three files: A.class  TestJni.class  TestJni.java

Use

```
javah -classpath . TestJni
```

to get .h file which is like:

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class TestJni */

#ifndef _Included_TestJni
#define _Included_TestJni
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     TestJni
 * Method:    print
 * Signature: (LA;)V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_TestJni_print
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

Rename it to MyJni.h by

```
mv TestJni.h MyJni.h
```

Create MyJni.c by

```
vim MyJni.c
```

the content of MyJni.c is:

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
#include "MyJni.h"
/* Header for class TestJni */

#ifndef _Included_TestJni
#define _Included_TestJni
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     TestJni
 * Method:    print
 * Signature: (LA;)V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_TestJni_print
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jobject o){
    jclass cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, o);
    jmethodID mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "show", "()V");
    (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, o, mid);

}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

Build .so file by

```
gcc -fPIC -shared -o libMyJni.so MyJni.c -I. -I$JAVA_HOME/include -I$JAVA_HOME/include/linux
```

And now I have 5 files [A.class  libMyJni.so  MyJni.c  MyJni.h  TestJni.class  TestJni.java] in my directory: /home/grid/code/tmp

Run java program:

```
java -cp . -Djava.library.path=. TestJni
```

Now I get the Error which is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: TestJni.print(LA;)V
    at TestJni.print(Native Method)
    at TestJni.main(TestJni.java:10)
```

I am coding under Ubuntu 14.10 and gcc program is the default one.
I really not able to figure out what is wrong.
Please help me to correct the program.
Thank you very much in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the

```
#ifndef _Included_TestJni
#define _Included_TestJni

...

#endif
```

from the **source file**. You've already `#define`d the include guard in the header, so this effectively comments out the code.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is just what I am looking for. But what did the program actually do if the codes appear twice both in source file and hearder?

Comment: You `#include` the header in the source file, which has the same effect as writing the contents of the header in place of the `#include` directive. Since the header `#define`s the `_Included_TestJni` macro, it is defined after this place. Later in the source, you say `#ifndef _Included_TestJni`, meaning: Use this stuff if `_Included_TestJni` is not defined. Because `_Included_TestJni` is defined, the stuff is not used, and the function is not compiled. Therefore it is not in the library, and therefore the JVM cannot find it there.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `#include "MyJni.h"` or

```
#ifndef _Included_TestJni
#define _Included_TestJni
//..
#endif
```

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: TestJni.print(LA;)V` this usually happen when JNI can't find the symbol definition in your library. You can use `nm` to analyze the JNI function you call to see if it is defined and exported in your library.

```
$ nm libMyJni.so 
00000000000005ac T Java_TestJni_print
0000000000200e40 a _DYNAMIC
0000000000200fe8 a _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
                 w _Jv_RegisterClasses
0000000000200e20 d __CTOR_END__
0000000000200e18 d __CTOR_LIST__
```

Comment: The tips of nm is really helpful when checking .so files. Thanks a lot!
Could you please explain about the conflict between `#include "MyJni.h"` and `#ifndef _Included_TestJni
#define _Included_TestJni
//..
#endif`?

Answer (score -1):

You can try using `System.load`. iirc `System.loadLibrary` loads .so/.dll files from the default location. `System.load` should work with an absolute path to the .so/.dll file.

Comment: I tried to use `System.load("/home/grid/code/tmp/libMyJni.so");` instead. But it ends up the same. I think it should be something wrong about the coding. Do you think so?

Comment: @krave maybe it has something to do with the renaming? It has been a while since I've done JNI..

Comment: The error isn't coming from `load()` or `loadLibrary()`. It is coming when he calls the native method.